# Show for $\epsilon > 0$ there is a simple function g such that $\int |f-g| d \mu \leq \epsilon$.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$

I am trying to show for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a simple function $g:X \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\int |f-g| d \mu \leq \epsilon$.

This is the proof. 
f is integrable so by definition $f=f^+ - f^-$ where $f^+$ and $f^-$ are both non negative and integrable. How do we know they are non negative and integrable? is it just by definition?

So the problem is reduced to non negative integrable functions.

So we have $\int f d \mu = sup \{ \int g : g$ is a simple function and g $\leq f $ a.e $\}$ by definition.

How do we get from this step to saying $\int | f - g| d \mu = \int f d \mu - \int g d \mu$?

Comment: I think you mean $h = |f - g|$ is integrable so both $h^+, h^-$ are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually people define for $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$,
$$ f^ + =  \left \{ \begin{array}{cc} f & f \geq 0 \\ 0 & f < 0 \end{array} \right. \quad \& \quad f^ - =  \left \{ \begin{array}{cc} -f & f \leq 0 \\ 0 & f > 0 \end{array} \right.$$
So both are clearly non-negative. If $|f|$ is integrable, notice that $|f| = f^+ + f^-$, thus we must have $f^+$ and $f^-$ integrable by linearity. Also, you never say the last step you wrote, you want to show that if $ |f - g| \leq |f^+ - g^+| + |f^- - g^-| \leq \epsilon$, then $\int f =  \int g \pm \epsilon $